# Trying to identify a stock sound effect

Tags: sound-effects, stock-effects

There's a sound effect I've heard every now and again, mostly in videogames. I really like the sound of it and want a nice sample of it for potential future projects, and I'm reasonably sure that it's a stock effect of some kind since it's been re-used so often, but not only do I have no idea how to search a library for the noise, since it doesn't specifically sound like much of anything, I also don't have any idea where to start on recreating it myself.

[Here's a link to the sound as used in the game where I first heard it - forgive the low quality, it's for a pretty old console.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/302993148513353729/768695760829022218/song289.wav)

Comment: It sounds like a synth portamento with a bit of delay - There may also be an arpeggio over the same notes but pushed down in the mix and possibly a little ring modulation. I can't be sure as I haven't tried to recreate it. I once tried to write a Manga script and marked it *SHIN* everywhere I wanted that sound - I don't know where I got that description from but I was young and only watched Akira, Ghost In The Shell and Patlabor 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

What game is your source "song289.wav" from? It's reminiscent of a classic anime sound effect, where if you process most sounds with a specific effects chain including reverb, it will end up sounding similar.

I highly recommend these resources, this tutorial is a marvelous breakdown:

You can also make similar sound effects with Tsugi's DSP Anime, then process them to make them "wetter":

http://tsugi-studio.com/web/en/products-dspanime.html